# Not able to receive cookie in react from django rest api : getting error (Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’

Tags: reactjs, typescript, django-rest-framework, axios

Im trying set cookie from server using axios in react app .
but getting error
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/login. (Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’)

This is login page

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component, SyntheticEvent } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import './public.css';

class Login extends Component {
    email = "";
    password = "";
    state = {
        redirect: false
    }



    submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await axios.post('login', {
            "email": this.email,
            "password": this.password
        }, 
        { 
            withCredentials: true 
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })

        this.setState({
            redirect: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to={'/'} />
        }
        return (

            <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.submit}>
                <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                <div className="form-floating">
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com"
                        onChange={e => this.email = e.target.value}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password"
                        onChange={e => this.password = e.target.value}
                    />
                </div>
                <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

This is rest api :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    password1 = request.data.get('password')

    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

    if user is None:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('user not found')

    if not user.check_password(password1):
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('password does not match')

    responce = Response()

    token = generate_access_token(user)

    responce.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
    responce.data = {
        'jwt': token
    }

    return responce
```

**Edit :**
im able to set cookie using postman
[image]

this is the header
[image]

Comment: add `responce["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"]=True` before returning the response,  however there should be a `CORS` config in django to avoid using this work around. take a look at this https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: i added the following line in my rest api its still not working. i have  configured CORS , normal api call is working fine but its throwing error only when im trying to set cookie

Comment: did you test it with `postman` or `cURL` to see if the headers are correctly set ?

Comment: yes i tested with postman its working fine

Comment: I can't see the `cors` headers in the reponse. are they hidden or simply not added ? Note that cors restrictions are implemented in web browsers

Comment: ii solved error , i forgot to add CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True in settings.py file in  server. thanks for your time